# Java Regular Expression Negative Look Ahead Finding Wrong Match

Tags: java, regex

Assume I have the following string.

```
create or replace package test as
-- begin null; end;/
end;
/
```

I want a regular expression that will find the semicolon not preceded by a set of `"--"` double dashes on the same line. I'm using the following pattern `"(?!--.*);"` and I'm still getting matches for the two semicolons on the 2nd line.

I feel like I'm missing something about negative look aheads but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Please post the full relevant code. Are you splitting the multiline string?

Comment: Do you want to match the second semicolon on the second line, or only the third one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match semicolons *only* on the lines which do not start with `--`, this regex should do the trick:

`^(?!--).*(;)`

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/nI5dH1/9)

I only made a few changes from your regex:

1. Multi-line mode, so we can use `^` and `$` and search by line
2. `^` at the beginning to indicate start of a line
3. `.*` between the negative lookahead and the semicolon, because otherwise with the first change it would try to match something like `^;`, which is wrong

(I also added parentheses around the semicolon so the demo page displays the result more clearly, but this is not necessary and you can change to whatever is most convenient for your program.)

Comment: Thank you that's what I was missing. I actually thought multiline meant it would consider all lines not that it would look at it a line at a time.

Comment: Yup, if you want to consider the entire string at once, that's global mode. If you did it in that way I think you'd have to replace the `^` with `\n`, but multiline seemed to make more sense for your input :)

Comment: what if the dash dash isn't at the start of the line, eg `foo -- end;`? Your regex won't work then. and btw, your regex is the same as `^(?!--).*;`

Comment: Is that a requirement? I thought it was supposed to match at the start of the line, but maybe I misunderstood since there was only the one example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you need is a negative lookbehind `(?<!)` and not a negative lookahead `(?!)` since you want to check what's behind your potential match.

Even with that, you won't be able to use the negative lookbehind in your case since the Java's regex engine does not support variable length lookbehind. This means that you need to know exactly how many characters to look behind your potential match for it to work.

With that said, wouldn't be simpler in your case to just split your String by linefeed/carriage return and then remove the line that start with "--"?

Comment: How come the examples at http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-2/ show a negative lookahead matching things behind the match.

Comment: I saw your example and there's clearly and error on there website.
"The theft was a serious incident" match with “(?!.*theft).*incident.*”

Answer (score 0):

The reason `"(?!--.*);"` isn't working is because the negative look ahead is asserting that when positioned before a `;` that the next two chars are `--`, which of course matches every time (`;` is always not `--`).

In java, to match a `;` that doesn't have `--` anywhere before it:

```
"\\G(((?<!--)[^;])*);"
```

To see this in action using a `replaceAll()` call:

```
String s = "foo; -- begin null; end;";
s = s.replaceAll("\\G(((?<!--)[^;])*);", "$1!");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
foo! -- begin null; end;
```

Showing that only semi colons before a double dash are matched.